# How can I include the mouse pointer using a command-line screenshot utility?

Tags: xorg, mouse, screenshot, mouse-pointer

I'd like to do this without giving feedback to the user as well, because a program I'm making will use it many times.

What didn't work:

- `scrot` (No mouse pointer)
- `import -window root` (No mouse pointer)
- `xwd -root` (No mouse pointer)
- `fbgrab` (I'm not using a framebuffer, apparently)
- `gnome-screenshot -p` (Big, ugly flash + sound)
- `shutter` (It took a *second and a half*!)

It would also be great if it would be fast (scrot takes ~ .1 sec to run).
It's fine if the mouse cursor is added later through additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, was just looking for the same, and I stumbled upon this man page: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/scrot/scrot.1.en.html where I could see:

```
...
-p, --pointer
    Capture the mouse pointer.
...
18 July 2020    scrot-1.4
```

... and it links to a Github:

https://github.com/resurrecting-open-source-projects/scrot

Obviously, no apt for this on Raspbian Stretch, so I had to build it from source - but the `--pointer` option seems to work fine.